# objective c warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am parsing an XML but having some problem regrading its attribute. I wan to fetch a value and want to convert into int. in my .h file I have declared

```
int *count;
```

and set property (nonatomic , readwrite)int *count;

in .m file

```
self.count = [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"count"] intValue];
```

but it gives error " warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast "

what is wrong ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *count;
```

:O

it shoud be
int count;

Answer (score 4):

Because you have declared your instance variable as a pointer to an `int` instead of as an `int`.  Drop the `*` from the instance variable and the property declaration and make sure the property is `assign` not `retain`.

Answer (score 3):

It should just be:

```
int count
```

You don't want to use a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

use int count that is enough.dont use pointer..